# 400 InvalidAuthenticationToken on graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dVPa.png)
Question: Why am I getting 40x when same token work on other rest calls, but not calendars. I works on emails, users etc.

I got the Access Token & Auth.
Getting Token:

```
authentication_endpoint = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/'
        resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com"
        context = adal.AuthenticationContext(authentication_endpoint + tenantId)
        token_response = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(resource, clientId, clientKey)
        access_token_gmc = token_response.get('accessToken')
        print("FD:::access_token-graphmicrosoft:", access_token_gmc)
```

What Works:

```
endpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getOffice365ActiveUserDetail%28period%3D%27D7%27%29"
        print("FD:O365:CalendarList-ActvUsers:" + endpoint)
        headers = {"Authorization": 'Bearer ' + access_token_gmc}
        response = requests.get(endpoint, headers=headers)
```

With same token - I tried this and it doesnt work:

```
endpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars"
        print("FD:O365:CalendarList:" + endpoint)
        headers = {"Authorization": 'Bearer ' + access_token_gmc}
        response = requests.get(endpoint, headers=headers)
```

Error:

```
FD:O365:CalendarList:https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars
('FD::0365:CalendarsList:', 400, u'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars')
('FD::0365:CalendarsList-Response', <Response [401]>)
('FD:0365:CalendarsList-Text:', u'{\r\n  "error": {\r\n    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",\r\n    "message": "Access token is empty.",\r\n    "innerError": {\r\n      "request-id": "3237....e",\r\n      "date": "2018-10-24T23:06:20"\r\n    }\r\n  }\r\n}')
```

Check Image:

Comment: I would double check to make sure you are passing in a value for access_token_gmc, since the error is saying its empty.

Comment: What worries me is "Access token is empty." .

Comment: Permission:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_calendars

Comment: Resolved: There is NO issue. I was requesting it twice, First with Auth and Second with out Auth. It is second one that is failing. I dont need second one any more.

Comment: Have you granted your permission for Microsoft graph?

Answer (score 0):

In your request for the token, you only use the `clientid` and `clientkey`, by this way, there is no related information about `me` in the token. You should add the user information(username and password) in the request body for the token, then you could use this token to do your following request.

And the required permissions:
[image]

I use the following way to get the user access_token:
[image]

And the response for the request is:

[image]

The error 404 is because there are no any calendars for `me`.